# Snackbar shown under view

Tags: android, canvas, overlay, android-snackbar, android-framelayout

I am using snackbar to alert user on exiting application, It works well on most of devices but on few devices like GALAXY A5(android version 5.0.2) it goes under my view like [image: this]

what's the problem?

Comment: Use custom toast instead and assign device width

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am using a linearlayout with buttons as children, but this problem happended when i didn't use any background for the linearlayout. I used transparent background and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this , i had the similar problem and fixed by using this
Put this after initiliazing views

```
 ViewCompat.postOnAnimation(coordinatorLayout, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(coordinatorLayout);
            }
        });
```